# MySQL 2D Ordering

Tags: mysql, levels

I have a query that gets information from multiple rows/tables and the result is a product list.

The list has to be separated in 3 (three) groups and each group have to be ordered on its own by the last modification datetime.

I get the ordering by groups, but I can't get the groups to order internally.

```
ORDER BY param1 DESC, IF(param2, 1, 0) DESC,param3 DESC, default_param
```

I want to make it (if possible):

```
ORDER BY param1 (modification_date DESC) DESC, IF(param2, 1, 0) (modification_date DESC)  DESC,param3 (modification_date DESC) DESC, default_param
```

Comment: Can you please add the rest of that query?

Comment: Its not a problem, but its a really long query and uses multiple tables/rows and to fill this with example would take a really long time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN param1 = 'Some value 1' THEN 1 END, g1.modification_date DESC,
   CASE WHEN param2 = 'Some value 2' THEN 1 END, g2.modification_date DESC,
   CASE WHEN Param3 = 'Some value 3' THEN 1 END, g3.modification_date DESC
```

Comment: Thing is that i don't know any of the parameter values, parameter is actually a bit strong word, this rows are more like markers to indicated where this product should go.

Comment: @Anonymous If you post that query or even a simplified  version of it just to see how it works then I can understand what you are trying to do therefore could help you. Can you??